# Отдельный index.php для каталога

Tags: nginx, redirect

Хочу настроить nginx, чтобы все запросы, начианющиеся с папки "/usa", вели на определённый index.php.

Для чего нужно: хочу разместить сайт в папке другого сайта, чтобы один сайт был доступен по адресу `site.com/usa`, а по адресу `site.com` был доступен другой сайт. Оба сайта должны принимать все запросы на свой index.php .

Когда обращаюсь по урлу `site.com/usa/test`, возвращает 404-ю ошибку, что нет такого урла. В принципе, логично, так как он должен перенаправиться на `site.com/usa/`, но я не знаю, как это сделать.

Содержимое файла конфига:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/site.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name site.com;

charset utf-8;

location ~* ^.+\.(rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|rtf|js|css|woff|otf|eot|fft)$ {
    expires max;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Comment: так в чём именно у вас проблема? что работает «не так»?

Comment: Когда обращаюсь по урлу site.com/usa/test, кидает 404 ошибку, что нет такого урла (в принципе логично), так как он должен перенаправиться на site.com/usa/, но я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. и заодно приведите текущее содержимое секции server. внести исправления можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте добавить ещё одну секцию:

```
location /usa {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /usa/index.php?$args;
}
```